# Split string by delimiter

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, multiline

I really can't find this answer...

I have multiline NSString called myString in XCode, and it is a HTML code. I need to navigate the string by lines, for example:

```
myString = @"<html>"
            "<body>"
            "<head><title>My Page</title>";
```

How can I access line per line? like:

```
LineOne = myString.Lines[0];
LineTwo = myString.Lines[1];
```

How can I do something like that in XCode???

I need something like the Memo component in Delphi...

Comment: it would be nice if you could mark the answer as the right one :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The most html strings will have (mostly invisible) newline delimiters for separating the line

```
NSArray *lines = [myHtmlString componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
NSString *lineOne = lines[0];
...
```