# How to get particular string from my response?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have received below string response

```
USA : United states of america
```

i need to get before ":" data's. Below I have posted sample what i need?

```
USA
```

Comment: Do u mean split by delimiter?
If so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558888/objective-c-split
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291505/split-string-by-delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
NSString*yourStr=@"USA : United states of america";
NSString *str=[yourStr componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][0];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: @Mano: Above answer do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you need to check if the ":" char is exists first because it will crash.

here is example for how to do it:

```
NSString *yourString = @"USA : bla bla bal";
NSRange range = [yourString rangeOfString:@":"];
if(range.location != NSNotFound) // string contains
{
    int indexOf = range.location;
    NSString *prefix = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, indexOf)];
    // prefix = "USA "
}
```

if you want you can trim the prefix string and remove all the empty spaces like this

```
NSString *trimmedString = [prefix stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                   [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```